# java program, using main and an external call

Tags: java

This might seem simple (or even stupid) but i cant think of a good way for searching what i want, even the title might not be completely right.
I have created a standard stand alone java program with a main() function that does what i want. I realized that I might need to call this program using some other program that i might need in the future. So i decided to create a constructor which will enable me to call from any java class.
My question is if this approach is the right one

```
public class GetUploadFiles {
    private static String[] arguments;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * expected a String[] containing the information needed
     * @param args the arguments passed
     */
   public GetUploadFiles(String[] args){
        arguments=args;   
   }

   /**
    * start the process of creating and uploading the zip file according to the arguments passed to the constructor
    * @throws IOException
    */
   public static void upload() throws IOException{
       startProcess(arguments);
       System.exit(0);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        startProcess(args);
        System.exit(0);
    }

   /**
    * start the process 
    * @param args
    * @throws IOException
    */
   public static void startProcess(String[] args) throws IOException{
      //my code is here
      }
}//class
```

thank you

Comment: As your code is written now, your program will start in `main` (as it should), then immediately go into `startProcess` without touching any of your other methods (unless of course you call them in that method, which you don't show). As far as is this the right approach... I don't see anything glaringly wrong about passing in parameters that determine what branch of the code to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is an acceptable solution. One thing to note, your upload method should not be static. I would personally recommend something like this:

```
public class GetUploadFiles {
    private static String[] arguments;

    public GetUploadFiles(String[] args){
         arguments=args;   
    }

    /**
     * start the process of creating and uploading the zip file according to the arguments passed to the constructor
     */
    public void upload() throws IOException{
        startProcess()
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new GetUploadFiles(args).upload();
    }

    private void startProcess() throws IOException{
        //my code is here
        //Can just use arguments in here since class is no longer static.
    }
}
```

This simplifies your code somewhat and standardizes your usage of the class.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements, but in general, that's a valid approach, and in my experience it's a common idiom to have a utility class that can be imported and used by Java programs, but is also usable from the command line by including a main method.

One change you'll want, don't call System.exit(0) in upload, otherwise that will exit the calling program. You don't need the System.exit(0) in main either, although it doesn't really hurt anything like the one in upload would.